# RAILS 5: sort Model by association attribute average

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-associations

Model Hotel has many Review with attribute overall_score

I just want to sort hotels based on average of Review.overall_score

Comment: Which database?

Comment: Figured out. Created a method for Hotel Model: </br>
def overall_score
self.reviews.average(:overall_score)
end 

this can then be used with following:

Hotel.all.sort_by(&:overall_score)